# Format jsp page containing jstl tags

Tags: eclipse, jsp, format, jstl

I am using eclipse. It is formatting the java as well as html pages using `CTRL + SHIFT + F`.

But is it possible to format jsp pages with some java code and jstl tags?

If it is not possible with eclipse then any other tool will also work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+SHIFT+F also works for .jsp files. The formater settings are in

```
Window>Preferences>Web>JSP Files>Editor
```

Comment: Yes, it is there. But with default template it is not formatting properly. And I am new in creating new template for formatting.